# How Can I Wear Red's Wings Without Being Debuffed?

Tags: terraria

In Terraria there is an item that is unobtainable in the game unless you use cheats like inventory edits called Red's Wings.  These wings can only be worn by ReDigIt and if you wear them as a regular player you will get all of the debuffs as well as -1000 defense and 1% moving speed.  I  was wondering how I could wear those wings without getting any of the debuffs (being the cheater that I am) that usually come with it.

Comment: If you know how to do your own texture pack you could the spritesheet of a legit pair of wings with the spritesheet from reds (assuming you are able to find it anywhere online). It will be coded like the normal wings (no debuffs) but will look like red's. I've not tried this myself or know if anyone has before but I think it would be your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem with those Developer Items is that they are Hardcoded debuffs so unless you know how to replicate Red's character perfectly I think there is no way.
What I can think is maybe it is possible with mods. Maybe there is a mod that can rebuild the developer items so you can wear them without fear of debuffs.

Answer (score 1):

Since the 1.3 major update, all the devs' equipment is obtainable in-game and not harmful anymore to the player. The tooltip for most of these items has become "Great for impersonating devs"

How do you get them ?
Play on an expert map, defeat **hardmode bosses**, and collect the treasure bags.

Upon opening, these bags have a small chance of giving you a full set of one of the devs' armor. Some of the sets can even contains a weapon (such as Red's Throw, a yoyo), wings (many dev sets have these, but not all), or others items (for example : skiph's blood, the rarest dye item)

Also, Red's wings have lost the ability to fly infinitely or go through tiles.